# Iterate Condition over Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

i store information about (biological) sequences in a dataframe and the last column["seq"] just contains empty strings

```
      id             length start  end    flank ...  seq
0   QHMTJXYKWXRUKMQ     235      0  235      0  ...    
1   QOODMXKFPXOWNRH     255     27  227     55  ...    
2   ISVULHIYLPIIVFW     285     74  285     74  ...    
...
```

and have a Dict. with IDs and corresponding Sequences

```
{'QOODMXKFPXOWNRH': 'GCTTCTCGTGGAGTGAGTACGGTGTGCCTTCAAACTCTACTCCCACTAATAGCTTTTTGATGCCTTCTAGCAAGCCTCGCTAACCTCGACTTACCCCCCACTCTTAACCTACTGGGAGAACTCTCTGTGCTAGTAACCACGTTCTCCTGATCAAATATCACTCTCCTACTTACAGGACTCAACATACTAGTCACAGCCCTATACTCCCTCTACATATTTACCACAACCCCATCCAGCATCCAACTCAGACTACAG', 'ISVULHIYLPIIVFW': 'GAGCGAGACTCCGTCTCAAAAAAAAAGAAGAAATACATTGGTTTGGTCCAGAAAGGTGGGACGACTCAAAGGGCGGGGGGTTGGGAGGGGGTCGGAGGAAAAGGTTGGGGAACAGCTCAATAGGTTGTTGTTGATTTGGTTAAAAAATAGTAGAGGGATGATGCTAATAATTAGGCTGTGGGTGGTTGTGTTGATTCAAATTATGTGTTTTTTGGAAAGTCATGTCAGTGGTAGTAATATAATTGTTGGGACGATTAGTTTTAGCATTGGAGTAGGTTTAGGTTA',...}
```

Now i try to iterate over the Dict./Dataframe and add the sequence to the ID in the dataframe (if the Dict. contains that specific ID).

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['id'].map(dictionary)
```